# Key Input in javaFx 2.0

Tags: javafx-2, game-development

I am currently working on a javaFX 2.0 game and I want to know how to make it so when I type a specific key something will happen. Thank You for taking your time for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Make your root node focused and then write your logic in the `setOnKeyPressed` method.

Sample code:

```
root.setFocusTraversable(true);
root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent kEvent) {
        if (kEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            System.out.println("Space Bar pressed");
        }
    }
});
```